EF Core check if AsSplitQuery() was applied
I am using Entity Framework Core to query my SQL Server database. I was wondering weather there is a way to check if AsSplitQuery() was applied to an existing query before executing it? I know that, if you output query ToQueryString(), there will be a message saying:

This LINQ query is being executed in split-query mode, and the SQL shown is for the first query to be executed. Additional queries may also be executed depending on the results of the first query.

However, that doesn't seem as a clean solution to my problem.

I can check that by analysing query.Expression. But I cannot understand why it is needed?

@SvyatoslavDanyliv if query is executed in split query mode, for performance reasons I would first load Ids of all records that match my desired filters and pass those Ids as a list/array in Where (using the Contains method). If query is executed in single query mode, then I would use a subquery to get record IDs (therefore, I wouldn't load matching record Ids into the memory).

You can use a simple extension method which checks that AsSplitQuery is used in the query expression:
var isSplitQuery = query.IsUsingSplitQuery();

And the implementation:
public static class QueryRelationalExtensions
{
    public static bool IsUsingSplitQuery<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        var current = query.Expression;

        while (current is MethodCallExpression methodCall)
        {
            if (methodCall.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(RelationalQueryableExtensions))
            {
                if (methodCall.Method.Name == nameof(RelationalQueryableExtensions.AsSplitQuery))
                    return true;
                if (methodCall.Method.Name == nameof(RelationalQueryableExtensions.AsSingleQuery))
                    return false;
            }

            if (methodCall.Arguments.Count == 0)
                break;

            current = UnwrapConvert(methodCall.Arguments[0]);
        }

        return false;
    }

    [return: NotNullIfNotNull(nameof(ex))]
    static Expression? UnwrapConvert(Expression? ex)
    {
        if (ex == null)
            return null;

        switch (ex.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.ConvertChecked:
            case ExpressionType.Convert:
            {
                if (((UnaryExpression)ex).Method == null)
                    return UnwrapConvert(((UnaryExpression)ex).Operand);
                break;
            }
        }

        return ex;
    }
}

Note that this approach does not check QuerySplittingBehavior which can also be added, but with passing DbContext to the IsUsingSplitQuery method.

Thank you very much for the answer. Your answer completely fits my use-case. I am not really bothered about QuerySplittingBehaviour in DbContext, since I am not setting it globally

is there a way to detect weather query will be actually translated to split query (in case of defining query with AsSplitQuery(), but where that query is translated into single SQL query or statement - for example if that query doesn't include enumerable navigation properties)?

Yes, if you interested only in Include queries. With Select it is more complicated. It is detectable only during query translation. Maybe we can ask some internal translation service for that, but I'm not familiar with them.

Thank you for the answer and your effort. I will probably try asking that question (regarding translating from expressions to SQL query) in separate question.
